# Django - button to remove row in sqlite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-forms

I have a question.. I got a Django Application with a mailbox that shows a list with all the mails and their importance (priority to answer). clicking the button "Manage" goes to a view of a mail message.

Now I also want to add a "delete" button that will delete this email in the list aka the row from the sqlite3 database.

I have tried multiple things, because I saw this on multiple forums. My problem is that I'm quite new to Django and I don't know which answers I can combine with what I already have in my code.

This is what I have now (it doesn't work as I'm still trying to find working solutions)

**mailindex.html:**

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="{% url 'core:mail' mail.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Manage</a>
        <button type="submit" name="deletemail" value="deletemail" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Delete</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
class MailboxView(generic.ListView):
    extra_context = {"mailbox_page": "active"}
    model = MailMessage
    context_object_name = 'mails'
    template_name = 'core/mailbox/mailindex.html'

    def post(self, request):
        # if 'deletemail' in self.request.POST:
        if request.POST.get('deletemail'):
            mail = MailMessage.objects.get(pk=13)
            mail.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

**EDIT:**
I am a bit further: it now works that the button deletes email with ID 13... How can I send the mail.id to my function in `views.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Django will not trigger the `delete_mail_listing`, or any other method except the ones that are in the code flow of the `ListView`.

Probably the most elegant way to do this is working with a `DeleteView`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import DeleteView

class MailMessageDeleteView(LoginRequired, DeleteView):
    model = MailMessage
    success_url = reverse_lazy('mailbox')
```

In the `urls.py`, you can then register this view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', login_required(views.IndexView.as_view()), name='index'),
    path('mailbox', login_required(views.MailboxView.as_view()), name='mailbox'),
    path('mailbox/delete/<int:pk>/', views.MailMessageDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete')
]
```

and in the template you then submit to the `MailMessageDeleteView`:

```
<form  method="POST" action="{% url 'delete' pk=mail.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Delete</button>
</form>
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: This looks very good. I tried to edit my code, but struggle with the "from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin" as it can't find the package and I'm also not sure if I need it as I use another login for the users who enter the dashboard? I now get an error message: "Reverse for 'delete' not found. 'delete' is not a valid view function or pattern name." for the line: action="{% url 'delete' pk=mail.pk %}"

Comment: Please make sure that the `url` path you give is same as the `name` attributes value in path()

Comment: Also, try to keep the function name the same

Comment: @user2133561: the view needs to have `path(..., name='delete')`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hi, Yes I definitely see how it can't find my 'delete' function... I have made the path(..., name='delete'), but still it can't find my delete function, I clearly am not placing it right but have tried multiple locations in the scripts... where should I place this function?

Comment: @user2133561: did you use an `app_name = ...` in the `urls.py`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes I did: app_name = 'core' ..

Comment: @user2133561: then it is `{% url 'core:delete' pk=mail.pk %}`.

Comment: @user2133561: and `success_url = reverse_lazy('core:mailbox')`